# how create rspec mailgun api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I follow mailgun api https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#examples

```
def send_simple_message
  RestClient.post "https://api:YOUR_API_KEY"\
  "@api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages",
  :from => "Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>",
  :to => "bar@example.com, YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME",
  :subject => "Hello",
  :text => "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"
end
```

and put in ApplicationService and call in controller

```
SendMailService.new(param['email']).call
enter code here
```

my quetion is how create or wirte in rspec?

Comment: You're not going to need/want this. MailGun is very easy to integrate with ActionMailer. https://github.com/readysteady/mailgunner#actionmailer-integration

Answer (score 0):

In a test environment, take the result you would get from the post request, to spec it as realistically as possible.

But inside your spec you can use mocks!

`allow(RestClient).to receive(:post).and_return({whatever_you_want: 'test'})`

I would test any code depending on APIs like this.